# Avoid needing to declare "-a" on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

This should probably be a super easy question but I can't figure out what I have not done properly.

I run 5 apps on Heroku, on my first three ones I can use commands as:

```
git push heroku
```

whereas the new ones I have to explicitly declare

```
git push git@heroku.com:myappname.git
```

For the old ones, if I am in the correct folder on my local app I can use commands such as:

```
heroku logs
```

to see the logs of that app on Heroku, whereas with the new ones I have to specify

```
heroku logs -a myapp
```

It seems like I have missed something with my git "connection" with Heroku.

What have I missed?

Comment: `git remote -v`? Whats the results?

Comment: No results at all. Executing the command works fine but it gives no feedback.

Comment: Then sounds like the heroku git repo is not associated with your application. Docs suggest `$ heroku git:remote -a <repo_name>`
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Comment: Thanks, that lead me to the correct path. Write that as an answer and I will credit you for it!

Comment: git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:myapp.git was the exact answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The heroku git repo is not associated with your application, use:

```
git remote add heroku <repo_name>
```

Comment: Do elaborate some more please. Users coming from Google wouldn't know what this "conversation" is, or where to see it.